# Ist der Genitiv altmodisch geworden?

Tags: genitive

Kommt es irgendwem komisch vor, wenn man im Alltag den Genitiv benutzt?
Bspw. wenn man einem Freund sagt "Ich bin gekommen trotz des schlechten Wetters" oder "Das sind die Sachen meines Mannes" oder "mithilfe meines Kollegen konnte ich's schaffen" "Die Sofa ist immer noch guten Zustands".

Ich habe kollidierende Ansichten diesbezüglich bekommen von meinen deutschen Freunden. Manche betrachten es als gutes, schönes Deutsch, die anderen finden es spießig und hochnäsig!

Ich selbst finde den Genitiv schon schön, insbesondere das Extra-S bei Wörtern männlichen oder neutralen Geschlechts, und benutze ihn immer, wo er benutzt werden soll.

Bald fange ich mit meinem neuen Job an und möchte auf keinen Fall einen schlechten Ersteindruck hinterlassen! Ich interessiere mich für eure Meinungen.

Comment: "Ich interessiere mich für eure Meinungen" ist eine Einladung zum Schließen, wie Du inzwischen vielleicht bemerkt hast. Kannst Du die Frage so formulieren, dass sie objektiv beantwortbar ist?

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob diese Frage objektiv zu beantworten ist, von daher fällt mir keine Formulierung ein :/

Comment: Die Verwendung des Genitivs im vierten Beispielsatz klingt beinahe falsch und ist auf jeden Fall *sehr* ungewöhnlich. Ein genitivus qualitatis wird eher selten und vorwiegend in festen Wendungen wie "guten Mutes" verwendet. Eher würde es deshalb heißen "Das (!) Sofa ist immer noch *in gutem Zustand*" oder auch "Das Sofa ist immer noch *in einem guten Zustand*".

Comment: @DeeDuu Diese Form kenne ich als *absolutus* - Und für **Dinge** ist sie wirklich ungebräuchlich, weil eher für geistige und seelische Zustände gedacht (da tut sich das Sofa eher schwer...), wie "ich bin guten Glaubens", oder "finsteren Sinnes" - "ich bin guten Zustands" funktioniert deshalb irgendwie nicht.... Ich glaube, der Satz ist so *wirklich falsch*.

Comment: In den Arztbriefen wird es routinemäßig den Begriff "der Patient ist guten/schlechten Allgemeinzustandes" verwendet.

Comment: Einerseits: Schreibt der Arzt das auch über Sofas? Andrerseits: Wer behauptet, dass das richtig wäre? In meinen Arztbriefen habe ich die Formulierung so noch nicht gefunden.

Comment: @tofro Hängt es nicht vom Satz ab, in dem "guten Mutes" verwendet wird? In "Ich ging guten Mutes zur Versammlung" wäre "guten Mutes" klarerweise ein *absolutus*. In "Ich bin guten Mutes" hingegen wird "guten Mutes" als Prädikatsnomen verwendet, was m.E. bedeutet, dass es kein *absolutus* sein kann (sondern eben ein prädikativ verwendeter *qualitatis*).

Comment: @DeeDuu wahrscheinlich hast du recht - Mein Beispiel ist wirklich ein Prädikativ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eben weil der Genitiv vielfach als "bedroht" und von "Einfachsprachlern"(keine Wertung) oft (an den Stellen, wo er eigentlich richtig wäre) durch den Dativ verdrängt wird, gilt er oft als gehoben und wird oft von Menschen, die sich gehoben ausdrücken wollen, gerne verwendet.

Der *possesive* ("das Haus des Lehrers") und *attributive* ("die Segel des Schiffes") Genitiv wird in der geschriebenen Sprache durchaus oft verwendet. Viele (süddeutsche) Dialekte kennen allerdings gar keinen Genitiv, sondern verwenden "von" + Dativ, was viele deswegen auch als akzeptiert betrachten.

Der *partitive* Genitiv (*wir tranken reichlich süßen Weins*) ist wohl zusammen mit dem *absolutus* (*ich bin guten Mutes*) auf dem Rückzug. Im heutigen Deutsch werden beide Formen als extrem gehoben/förmlich betrachtet und der Anwender läuft Gefahr, als Snob betrachtet zu werden.

Eine Menge Verben, die traditionell den Genitiv regieren, werden inzwischen oft auch mit dem Dativ akzeptiert - Es gibt aber auch eine Entwicklung in die Gegenrichtung, bei der man beobachten kann, dass Präpositionen, die historisch sowohl Dativ als auch Genitiv regieren können, zunehmend mit dem Genitiv verwendet werden:

- *außer* der Reihe, *außer* Landes - dürfte genausogut auch mit Dativ stehen, Genitiv ist aber bevorzugt
- *binnen* dreier Tage bezahlt - Es war so kalt, dass ich *binnen Kurzem* total durchgefroren war
- *dank, laut, trotz, zufolge* sind ähnliche Beispiele, die traditionell wunderbar mit beiden Fällen funktionieren, zumindestens in der "gehobenen Sprache" zunehmend mit Genitiv verwendet werden.

Wegen der oben angeführten angenommenen "Noblesse" des Genitivs wird er auch oft zur Angelegenheit der [Hyperkorrektur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperkorrektur) - Weil sich jemand besonders gepflegt ausdrücken möchte, verwendet er den Genitiv an Stellen, wo er eigentlich gar nicht hingehört - ein paar Beispiele, wo oft ein Genitiv verwendet wird, obwohl ein Dativ oder eine passende weitere Präposition hingehört:

- <s>Das Hotel ist gegenüber des Postamts</s>
- <s>vis-á-vis des Rathauses ist ein Hotel</s>
- <s>Gemäß des Kaufvertrags überweise ich ...</s>

Ich befürchte, dein letzter Beispielsatz ("das Sofa ist guten Zustands") ist daher ein Fall von Hyperkorrektur - Es gibt zwar einen *Genitivus Absolutus*, der wird aber im Deutschen nur verwendet, wenn es um seelische oder geistige Zustände geht, wie in "ich bin guten Mutes" oder "ich bin froher Erwartung" - Für ein Ding wie ein *Sofa* und etwas profanes wie einen *Zustand* wäre die Anwendung sicher falsch.

Zusammengefaßt:

**<s>Um den Genitiv mache ich mir keine Sorgen</s>**

Ich mache mir keine Sorgen wegen des Genitivs

Ob man deswegen gleich eine "Genitivepedemie" wie bei dem von u.u. verlinkten *Belles Lettres*-Artikel herbeireden muss, finde ich allerdings zweifelhaft.

Comment: Was ist an *vis-à-vis der Post ist ein Hotel* falsch? *der Post* steht doch im Dativ?

Comment: Sollte schon einen Genitiv darstellen - Mach' ich halt 'n Rathaus draus...

Comment: Oh. Mein eigener Kommentar erinnert mich an den Witz von den zwei Polizisten, die eine Leiche vor dem Gymnasium finden und einen Bericht schreiben sollen: "Du, wie schreibt man eigentlich Gymnasium?" - "Weiss ich nicht - Komm, wir tragen ihn vors Rathaus".

Answer (score 3):

Viele Leute verwenden *Dativ* statt *Genitiv* aber das gilt meistens als umgangssprachlich. Es gibt sogar ein Buch "*Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod* von  Bastian Sick über dieses Thema.

Und mit dem gleichen Namen gibt es auch einen [witzigen Artikel](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-der-dativ-ist-dem-genitiv-sein-tod-a-267725.html).

> Der Dativ ist des Genitivs Freund und Gehilfe! Wenn zum Beispiel der
>   Genitiv im Plural nicht erkennbar ist, springt der Dativ für ihn ein
>   und leiht ihm eine Flexions-Endung: So heißt es nicht "wegen
>   Geschäfte", sondern "wegen Geschäften".

Ich bin auch kein Muttersprachler aber soviel wie möglich versuche ich, Genitiv zu verwenden und ich habe gesehen, dass die Muttersprachler sich sehr darüber freuen, wenn sie es sehen.

Comment: Note that Bastian Sick's books have to be taken with about a ton of salt - Not everything he claims is language reality.

Comment: @tofro That is true. One should not read this book to learn something new but to make fun of the everyday facts.

Answer (score 3):

> Das größte Bildungsbürgermärchen über die deutsche Sprache lautet, der
>   Genitiv wäre von hoher Güte, aber seine Zukunft bedroht, weil die
>   meisten Zeitgenossenden Genitiv einfach nicht mehr verstünden.
>   Tatsächlich leben wir in der größten Genitivepidemie aller Zeiten.

Eine ausführliche Betrachtung zum Genitiv findet sich bei [belleslettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/genitiv/genitiv-deutsche-sprache.php).

Kernaussagen, wie oben schon ersichtlich: Das Gegenteil ist wahr, der Genitiv greift um sich und zweitens: Wenn an vielen Stellen der Dativ im Gebrauch ist, dann kann die Vermeidung auch nicht falsch sein.

Comment: Was *belleslettres* hier sagt, ist mir (wieder einmal) ein bißchen zu plakativ und allgemein, mit viel Behauptung und wenig fundierter Begründung. **Hier** ist aber mMn wirklich was dran. Und dass er den Herrn Sick in die Pfanne haut, ist erstens modern und zweitens auch in meinem Sinne :)

Comment: Soll das fette HIER ein Link sein, oder wo ist wirklich was dran? Was konkret ist zu plakativ und zu allgemein? Was ist *Deine* Begründung? :) Ich habe mal stichprobenartig auf Radionachrichten und eine Sportübertragung im Radio geachtet, also nichts mit literarischem Anspruch und habe auch einige Genetive bemerkt, habe aber kein historisches Material zum Vergleich hergezogen (woher auch).

Answer (score 3):

Der Genitiv ist auf jeden Fall etwas für Liebhaber der deutschen Sprache. Man kann einen Satz häufig anders ausdrücken, um ihm zu entgehen, aber das ist Feigheit vor dem Feinde hat mein Vater immer gesagt. Der Genitiv ist schön und elegant und man sollte ihn so viel wie möglich benutzen, auch wenn einen das eventuell als einen Bildungsbürger auszeichnet.